# sql query serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server 2000. I want a serial number for output table.
So when I run this stored proc I get this error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table
>   '#tmpSearchResults1' can only be specified when a column list is used
>   and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I have tried with `set IDENTITY_INSERT  #tmpSearchResults1 on`

```
Create Procedure dbo.usp_mobile_All_KeyWord(@searchkey varchar(30))                                        
AS          
CREATE TABLE #tmpSearchResults        
(                                                 
 property_id varchar(255),                                                          
 property_number varchar(255),                                                          
 auction_date_reason  varchar(255)                                        
) 

INSERT INTO #tmpSearchResults         

SELECT              

 p.property_id, p.property_number, p.auction_date_reason                                                             
   FROM                                                              
 Pr p               
 INNER JOIN                                                              
 Au a ON p.auction_id = a.auction_id                                                                
 INNER JOIN                                         
 PrAdd pa ON p.property_id = pa.property_id                                        

 INNER JOIN state AS s ON s.state_id=pa.state                
 where            
   (        
   (p.archive = 'N'               

 AND                                                     
 a.show_on_site = 'Y'                                                              
 AND                                                              
 (        
 (        
 ((p.auction_date >= CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103), 103) and  (p.auction_date_reason is null or p.auction_date_reason = ''))        
 or         
 (p.auction_date <= CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103), 103) and  ( p.auction_date_reason = 'Accepting Offers' )))        
 and        

 pa.property_address_type_id = 1 )) )        
  and         
  (state_abbreviation=@searchkey or  s.state_name like '%'+''+ @searchkey +''+'%' or city  like '%'+''+ @searchkey +''+'%' or  pa.address1 like '%'+''+ @searchkey +''+'%'        
          or  pa.address2 like '%'+''+ @searchkey +''+'%')         
 )      

)         


 CREATE TABLE #tmpSearchResults1        
(            
i1 int identity,                                          
 property_id varchar(255),                                                          
 property_number varchar(255),                                                          
 auction_date_reason  varchar(255)    
)        
 insert into #tmpSearchResults1      

 select     
property_id ,                                                          
 property_number,                                                          
 auction_date_reason                                            

 from #tmpSearchResults       

 order by        
 case when charindex(@searchkey,state) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc,        
  case when charindex(@searchkey,statename) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc,        
 case when charindex(@searchkey,city) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc,         
 case when charindex(@searchkey,address2) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc,        
 case when charindex(@searchkey,address1) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc,        
 case when charindex(@searchkey,short_description) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc      

 select * from #tmpSearchResults1
```

Plz do help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The error code is very very very clear.**

The relevant portion is `...when a column list is used...`.

You need to specify your column list in the `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO #tmpSearchResults
(i1, 
 property_id,                                                          
 property_number,                                                          
 auction_date_reason)         

SELECT              

 p.property_id, p.property_number, p.auction_date_reason                                                             
   FROM...
```

Comment: @Sree - happy to help.  Pay close attention to the error codes, a lot of the time in SQL Server they are very specific and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a comma too much in the `SELECT` part of your second statement:

```
 insert into #tmpSearchResults1      

 select     
     property_id ,                                                          
     property_number,                                                          
     auction_date_reason  , <-- THIS ONE!!                                      

 from #tmpSearchResults
```

The last column of a `SELECT` statement must be without a comma.
So this would be correct:

```
 insert into #tmpSearchResults1      

 select     
     property_id ,                                                          
     property_number,                                                          
     auction_date_reason                                 

 from #tmpSearchResults
```

Second, did you read this part of the error message?

> An explicit value [...] can only be specified **when a column list is used**

The "column list" part means that you have to specify the columns in the `INSERT` part:

```
 insert into #tmpSearchResults1  
     (property_id, property_number, auction_date_reason)

 select     
     property_id ,                                                          
     property_number,                                                          
     auction_date_reason                                 

 from #tmpSearchResults
```

You can get away with not specifying the columns when the number of columns in the `SELECT` statement is the same as in the table in which they should be inserted (and if the data types match).
If one of these conditions is not met, you need to specify the columns because otherwise SQL Server doesn't know which value to insert into which column.